# Android won't open new activity from listview

Tags: java, android

The app stops working when clicking on the first item on the list! I tried writing the code in a couple of different ways but it still won't work! What am I doing wrong??

```
package com.vogella.android.filmapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String [] filmArray = {"Harry Potter", "No time to die", "Finding Dory", "Spider-Man",
                "The Avengers", "Little Women", "Dune"};

        ListAdapter theAdapter = new MyAdapter(this,filmArray);

        ListView film_list_view= findViewById(R.id.film_list_view);
        film_list_view.setAdapter(theAdapter);

   film_list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           if (position==0){
               Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), HarryPotter.class);
               startActivity(intent);
           }
       }
   });

    }
}
```

Help?

Comment: Logcat should tell you.

Comment: @PeterMmm Just did! Just realized I forgot to add in the manifest! Thanks!